# C++ , 'time' was not declared in this scope, without reason

Tags: c++, time, arduino, include

I'm building an Arduino sketch and I'm stuck with a strange error:

> 'time' was not declared in this scope

These are my includes:

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <DS3232RTC.h> //http://github.com/JChristensen/DS3232RTC
#include <Streaming.h> //http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/
#include <Time.h> //http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time
#include <Wire.h> //http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire
#include <TimeLib.h>
```

And this is the function where I get the error:

```
void wifiTimeSetup() {
  configTime(timezone * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
  Serial.println("Mi sto collegando al servizio per l'ora esatta tramite internet");
  while (!time(nullptr)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

The error comes up when including the Time.h and TimeLib.h libraries, but I need them too, to use my RTC module.

Comment: Did you install the library? (if it requires this)

Comment: yes I've installed the libraries, the code works until I include Time.h and TimeLib.h, maybe a conflict? I don't know.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be `std::time(nullptr)`

Comment: Bamar, I tried, same error

Comment: What's the difference between <Time.h> and <time.h>?  Does the compiler differentiate between case sensitivity in filenames?  (Hint: one is a system library).  You may need to specify the path for one of them, in the `#include` statement.

Comment: Probably none, I just discovered that TimeLib.h is the include that generates the problem, without it , the code works but I need TimeLib.h later :(

Comment: don't use both of the time libraries together. try using only one of those time libraries. I recommend timelib.h. Take a look at this interesting discussion: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=451360.0

Comment: Are you using `std::time` or something else?  Did you need to say that you are using `std::time`?  The `nullptr` argument is consistent with a common usage of `std::time`.

Comment: Where did you declare the `time` variable? Please post that part of the code, or, better, the whole sketch, reduced to the most important bits. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including both time.h and Time.h is generally not a good idea.

This is due to case sensitivity or insensitivity of the compiler your'e working 
with.

Apparently this conflict was already posted as a known issue:

https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/issues/74

> Some Arduino users are trying to use this library with libraries like RTCZero that #include  on case sensitive filesystems like macOS and older Windows. Here's a related issue: arduino-libraries/RTCZero#28
>   The compiler ends up including Time.h instead of the POSIX time.h inside the RTCZero library which causes compile errors. Would you be open to renaming Time.h in the library to avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using  `#include "time.h"`

Updating the Time library fixed my problem.